# Relationship on owned type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to define a one to many relationship on an owned type.

Here in my example,

- InboundRequest: principal entity
- RequestHistory: owned type
- RequestHistoryEntry : Dependency entity

```
public class InboundRequest : IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public RequestHistory History { get; private set; }
}
public class RequestHistory
{
    public IList<RequestHistoryEntry> HistoryEntries { get; set; }
}

public class RequestHistoryEntry
{
    public RequestState State { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

builder.Entity<InboundRequest>().OwnsOne(x => x.History);
```

Unfortunately EF Core gives me the following error:

> The relationship from 'RequestHistoryEntry' to
>   'InboundRequest.History#RequestHistory.HistoryEntries' is not
>   supported because the owned entity type
>   'InboundRequest.History#RequestHistory' cannot be on the principal
>   side.

Is there a way to have a one to many relationship between an owned type and a list of dependencies?

Comment: Why are you using an owned type? What table structure are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have two tables InboundRequest and RequestHistoryEntry. I know that I could do it without a owned type but I want to do this for the sake of code clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have a one to many relationship with owned types is if the owned entity is on the [*many* side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) of the relationship, in which case ef core will map it to a separate table by convention. What you are attempting is per se not possible [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#by-design-restrictions). However, in your particular case, why don't you get rid of `RequestHistory` altogether and make the list of `RequestHistoryEntry` as a collection of owned type to your `InboundRequest` as follows:

```
public class InboundRequest : IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public IList<RequestHistoryEntry> HistoryEntries { get; set; }
}

public class RequestHistoryEntry
{
    public RequestState State { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

builder.Entity<InboundRequest>().OwnsMany(x => x.HistoryEntries);
```

That should get rid of the error as well as achieve your desired relationship to your dependent entity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a list of objects as a owned type, because the columns of your History table are added to the InboundRequest table. The column count of the table must be fixed and not dynamic.

If you write the following:

```
public RequestHistoryEntry HistoryEntries { get; set; }
```

Then your InboundRequest table looks like that (or similar):

> | Id | RequestHistory_State | RequestHistory_Timestamp | RequestHistory_Id |

If you are using a List of RequestHistoryEntry, then the column count is not clear.
Therfore you have to use a separate table for it.

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong @Marco. Having a list of owned types is absolutely possible in ef core. However having a navigation property to another non-owned entity from within the `RequestHistory` class is illegal because by definition RequestHistory is part of its owner and should not refer to outside object directly.